# Needing some explanation of a MySQL ranking query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm hoping to get some explanation on a ranking query I've come across. I have a similar setup where I've got a points field that I want to order by, but can't for the life of my understand this query: http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php#460

I don't understand what the join is actually doing, and why if I don't include the group by statements, I just get one record that is completely jumbled and incorrect. I always see Group By statements as limiting the number of results, but this query seems to be adding them to the final results set (as without the group by, you get one row returned)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is essentially doing this:

For each row in the original votes table, count how many rows (in the same table) have votes <= to that row.  The count is the same as the rank.

The JOIN is needed to link the votes table to each individual row in the votes table.

GROUP BY is needed when you have a COUNT() in your select list.  For each person, the query is counting how many rows it finds that have votes <= for each person.  The GROUP BY with the COUNT is limiting the number of results of the JOIN results which is a multiplication of the original votes table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I'm having trouble seeing how the JOIN plays into this. The JOIN's ON statement looks to me like it should be a WHERE condition.

Is the JOIN bringing back every row in the table meeting those conditions, for each record in the original table, which the COUNT then counts how many actually came back? If thats all correct, the GROUP BY is then where I'm getting lost. Is it GROUPING the join table?

Comment: Yes, the join is bringing back every row in the table meeting those conditions. If you were to replace the COUNT with v2.names, and remove the GROUP BY, the results set would be multiplied to illustrate this.